# my app-admin.blade.php Trying to get the 'full_name' property from a non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7, laravel-6

app-admin.blade.php

```
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-user-link" id="dropdown-user" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <div class="user-nav d-sm-flex d-none">
                <span class="user-name font-weight-bolder">{{ Auth::user()->'nama_lengkap' }}</span>
                  <span class="user-status">Admin</span>
              </div>
                <span class="avatar">
                  <img class="round" src="{{ Auth::user()->getAvatar() }}" alt="avatar" height="40" width="40">
                  <span class="avatar-status-online"></span>
                </span>
            </a>
```

TicketController.php

```
use App\Model\Ticket;
use App\Model\User;
use App\Model\Kategori;
use App\Model\Prioritas;
use App\Model\Status;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Ticket::with('user','kategori','prioritas','status')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.crud_ticket.index', compact('data'));
    }
```

after I run it, an error appears that I don't know
on my master.blade.php

> Trying to get the 'full_name' property of non-object (View: C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ Helpdesk \ resources \ views \ layouts \ app-admin.blade.php)

Comment: `full_name` doesn't appear in that code and the error shows up in `app-admin.blade.php`, not `master.blade.php`, but `Auth::user()->'nama_lengkap'` should be `Auth::user()->nama_lengkap` (without quotes)

Comment: does not work @brombeer

Comment: You have to share `app-admin.blade.php` file, not `master.blade.php` as there is no problem there.

Comment: As I said, the code you posted is in no way related to the error you posted. Please [edit] your question and post `app-admin.blade.php` where the error occurs

Comment: I've changed master.blade.php but it doesn't work

Comment: Please don't tagged multiple version with your question

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there is no record with the desired ID in the table that wants to returns the `full_name` field to you. One way to manage this error, you can use `is_null` method. for example:

```
$user = User::find($id);
is_null($user) ? '' : $user->full_name
```